# Mail merge with attachments and cc for MS Word

Tags: beginner, vba, email, ms-word

I am very new to coding and really started a few weeks ago for a new job I have. out of necessity, I am slowly learning VBA (which I can't say is very easy...) I started by recording macros in Excel and copy/paste bits of VBA codes from the internet. A good chunk of them came from SO, which prompted me to join and try to answer questions myself to contribute back.
In any case, I'm posting a Word macro that I have that runs mail merge and allows to add cc recipient and attachments and I am seeking comments and tips to improve my skills. It runs fine, I'm just looking for suggestions on how to write better code - because I'm sure there are lots that can be improved.

PS. The answer to all questions "Why are you doing X?" is: Beacuse it works!

```
Sub MergeWithAttachments()
Dim Source As Document, Maillist As Document, TempDoc As Document
Dim Datarange As Range
Dim i As Long, j, a, k As Long
Dim bStarted, DialogB As Boolean
Dim oOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim mysubject As String, message As String, title As String
Dim mailWord As Object
Dim oData As New DataObject
Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim Filepath As String
Dim Arr() As String


    Set Source = ActiveDocument
    ' Check if Outlook is running.  If it is not, start Outlook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Set oOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        bStarted = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

If MsgBox("Do you want to set Outlook to work offline?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    If oOutlookApp.Session.Offline = False Then
    oOutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders.GetFirst.GetExplorer.CommandBars.FindControl(, 5613).Execute
    End If
End If


'Prompt the user to select the Directory
MsgBox "Please select the directory for the mail merge."
' Open the Directory mailmerge document and cancel if Cancel button is selected
    DialogB = Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen).Show
    If Not DialogB Then
        MsgBox ("Mail merge canceled!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set Maillist = ActiveDocument
    ' Show an input box asking the user for the subject to be inserted into the email messages
    message = "Enter the subject to be used for each email message."    ' Set prompt.
    title = "Email Subject Input"    ' Set title.
    ' Display message, title
    mysubject = InputBox(message, title)
    If (StrPtr(mysubject) = 0) Then
        MsgBox "Mail merge canceled!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
    Do Until Len(mysubject) <> 0
        MsgBox "Cannot send emails with no subject. Please enter a subject line. Select Cancel to stop the mail merge."
        mysubject = InputBox(message, title)
            If (StrPtr(mysubject) = 0) Then
                MsgBox "Mail merge canceled!"
                Exit Sub
            End If
    Loop
End If
' Iterate through the Sections of the Source document and the rows of the catalog mailmerge document,
' extracting the information to be included in each email.
If MsgBox("Are you adding cc email recipients?", vbYesNo, "CC email") = vbNo Then
    GoTo No_cc
    Else
    If MsgBox("Are your cc email recipients in the second column from the left?", vbYesNo, "CC in second column") = vbYes Then
        GoTo Add_cc
        Else:
        If MsgBox("Cc email recipients need to be in the second column. Please rework your directory accordingly.", vbOKOnly, "Cancelling Mail Merge") = vbOK Then
        Exit Sub
        End If
End If
No_cc:
For j = 1 To Source.Sections.Count - 1
    Source.Sections(j).Range.Copy
    Set oItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set mailWord = oItem.GetInspector.WordEditor

    With oItem
        .Subject = mysubject
        mailWord.Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
        Set Datarange = Maillist.Tables(1).Cell(j, 1).Range
        Datarange.End = Datarange.End - 1
        .To = Datarange
        For i = 2 To Maillist.Tables(1).Columns.Count
            Set Datarange = Maillist.Tables(1).Cell(j, i).Range
            Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
            Datarange.End = Datarange.End - 1
            Filepath = Datarange.Text
            If FSO.FileExists(Filepath) = False Then
                a = a + 1
                ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To a)
                Arr(UBound(Arr)) = .To
                GoTo NextEmail1
            Else
            .Attachments.Add Trim(Datarange.Text), olByValue, 1
            End If
        Next i
        .Send
    End With
    Set oItem = Nothing
NextEmail1:
Next j

GoTo Merge_finished

Add_cc:
If MsgBox(Source.Sections.Count - 1 & " emails are about to be sent. Do you want to continue?", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
    MsgBox "Mail merge canceled."
    Exit Sub
End If
For j = 1 To Source.Sections.Count - 1
    Set oItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Source.Sections(j).Range.Copy
    Set mailWord = oItem.GetInspector.WordEditor

    With oItem
        .Subject = mysubject
        mailWord.Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
        'Take row J and look in the first column to get the To address
        Set Datarange = Maillist.Tables(1).Cell(j, 1).Range
        Datarange.End = Datarange.End - 1
        .To = Datarange
        'code for adding cc emails. Currenlty set to read column 2 as cc emails, since column 1 is To
        Set Datarange = Maillist.Tables(1).Cell(j, 2).Range
        Datarange.End = Datarange.End - 1
        .CC = Datarange.Text
        'Since the first two columns are To and CC, the first Path will be on the 3rd column, so initially, i = 3 and will continue until there are no more columns
        For i = 3 To Maillist.Tables(1).Columns.Count
            Set Datarange = Maillist.Tables(1).Cell(j, i).Range
            Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
            Datarange.End = Datarange.End - 1
            Filepath = Datarange.Text
            If FSO.FileExists(Filepath) = False Then
                Debug.Print "Email (with error) number "; j
                a = a + 1
                ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To a)
                Arr(UBound(Arr)) = .To
                GoTo NextEmail
            Else
            .Attachments.Add Trim(Datarange.Text), olByValue, 1
            End If
        Next i
        .Send
        End With
    Set oItem = Nothing
NextEmail:
Next j

Merge_finished:
End If

'open an Excel workbook with the list of emails that could not be sent
If a <> 0 Then
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
'Dim objDoc As Excel.Workbook
Dim Current As Worksheet
'Dim eStarted As Boolean
'Dim rng1, rng2 As Range
Dim c As Integer


MsgBox "There were issues with some attchment(s) when trying to send emails. A list of recipient for whom an email was not sent because of invalid path(s) to attachment(s) will be generated in an Excel file." & vbCrLf & _
        "Please check the file path(s) and the directory used for this mail merge and try again.", vbCritical, "Mail merge error"


Set objExcel = New Excel.Application

With objExcel

    .Workbooks.Add
    Set Current = objExcel.Sheets(1)
    Current.Range("a1").Value2 = "List of recipient for whom an email was not sent"
    .Visible = True

End With

For c = 1 To a
    Current.Cells(c + 1, 1) = Arr(c)
Next c


End If

Maillist.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
'  Close Outlook if it was started by this macro.
If bStarted Then
    oOutlookApp.Quit
End If
'return a summary message box with number of emails sent
If a <> 0 Then
MsgBox Source.Sections.Count - a - 1 & " messages have been sent." & vbCrLf & _
    a & " emails could not be sent (see Excel file).", vbOKOnly, "Summary"
    Else
    MsgBox Source.Sections.Count - 1 & " messages have been sent."
End If

'Clean up
Set oOutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```